# Gulp compass without config.rb

Tags: gulp, gulp-compass

I'm struggling to get gulp-compass working correctly **without using a config.rb** file.

Prerequisites:

- I don't want to use a config.rb file
- I need to use compass (can't just use SASS)

[The docs say](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-compass):

```
var compass = require('gulp-compass'),
path = require('path');

gulp.task('compass', function() {
  gulp.src('./src/*.scss')
    .pipe(compass({
    project: path.join(__dirname, 'assets'),
    css: 'css',
    sass: 'sass'
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/temp'));
});
```

But I can't find the following information anywhere:

1. What `path = require('path')` does.  This doesn't seem to be a gulp-plugin.
2. What `path.join` does exactly.
3. What `__dirname` is and should it be changed?

If anyone can clear this up it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Path](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html) is a *Node* core module. Its [join](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2) method allow you to join arguments that will construct a normalised path. `__dirname` refers to the directory of the file in which it is used.

Basically it's simply to refers to the `assets` directory which is in the same folder as your gulpfile.

By the way, the [gulp-ruby-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass) plugin has a `compass` option that you can set to `true`.